# How to get innertext of all li elements in an list with puppeteer-sharp and XPath in C#

Tags: c#, xpath, puppeteer-sharp

I am trying to get all the innertext from a list of "li"-elements. It seems I am hitting something, there are 19 elements in the variable `has`, but I don't know how to pick out the actual innertext values:

```cs
string xpath = "//h1[@title='UL']//li";
IElementHandle[] has = await ((IPage)pageTabel).XPathAsync(xp);
IJSHandle ha = has[0].GetPropertiesAsync("value");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think e.g.

```
foreach (var listItem in has)
{
    Console.WriteLine((await listItem.GetPropertyAsync("textContent")).RemoteObject.Value.ToString()); 
}
```

would work. I don't know whether browser's also implement the (originally IE only) innerText property, if they do then of course above doing `GetPropertyAsync("innerText")` instead should also work.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd prefer a strongly typed experience then [PuppeteerSharp.Dom](https://github.com/ChromiumDotNet/PuppeteerSharp.Dom) provides a set of extensions to `PuppeteerSharp`.

Install [PuppeteerSharp.Dom](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PuppeteerSharp.Dom/) from `Nuget.org` then you can use the strongly typed extensions.

```cs
// Add using PuppeteerSharp.Dom; to access XPathAsync<T>

string xpath = "//h1[@title='UL']//li";
var has = await ((IPage)pageTabel).XPathAsync<HtmlListItemElement>(xpath);

foreach (var listItem in has)
{
    var textContent = await listItem.GetTextContentAsync();
}
```